# Should I misspell my name if it has a non-standard character?

Tags: resume

One of my last names is Fernández. As you see, it has the character **á**, which is a non-standard character.

If I'm applying for jobs in my country, there is no problem as here we use such character, but if I'm applying for a job in a country where English is the main language, shall I misspell my name writing **a** instead of **á** to prevent format issues? Like Fern?ndez.

I'm really not sure about what to do. On one hand, if I misspell it and whoever reads my resume knows Spanish, will think I have misspelling issues. On the other hand, if I write it correctly, resume screeners may not properly identify my name.

Comment: **Comments removed.** Comments should be used to clarify/improve the question. For extended discussion, please use [chat].

Comment: I don't think it's opinion based because there are objective factors behind it.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a data point: I put your last name Fernández into LinkedIn and it returned 43807, I then tried it with Fernandez and also got 43807. Therefore the software at LinkedIn transliterates the á to a.

I don't think that anybody involved in hiring in the US will care which way you spell your last name. But be aware that some systems will not accept the á and will convert it to a. For example email addresses. Though if it could accept the á it might use an alias to link the two spellings.

Comment: While that may be the case, it's also possible (although unlikely) that there are equal numbers of Fernández and Fernandez registered on LinkedIn.

Comment: In Google it is 37900000 (á) vs 51900000 (a). If the system converts it to a, there is no problem at all. The problem is when the system converts it to ? or any other symbol.

Comment: These types of issues is what keeps programmers up late at night.  If the programmers of the job board / HR software haven't taken these things into account then you won't see the same results.

Answer (score 2):

It's good practice to tweak your CV when applying for vastly different jobs - for example to emphasise experience in a job older than your last/current one if the older experience is more relevant to the job you're applying for.

I'd suggest the same applies here - if you're concerned them simply keep two copies of your CV and use the appropriate one for each job.